# When inserting a record with name which is already existing in record of custom setting, It gives an error that name already exist?

Tags: customsetting

I have custom setting with three records there is four fields name, price, sales, active. I want to insert a new record with same name but different others field values.I have a VF page there is a picklist with three values which will be the name of the custom setting, When I select a picklist it will be the record of custom setting with four fields, When there is no any record with the name, it is inserted but when already that name there it is giving an error that name already existed.
 I want new record to insert with same name, Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the custom setting data is retrieved by name. so the name field must be unique. so that the user can retrieve a single custom setting record. you must insert your new record with different name.